# MongoDB Perl update command

Tags: mongodb, perl

I would like to update a field without losing the others fields of the collection from perl script.

for example I have this collection :

```
{
"userid": 1234,
"username": "tester",
"password": "*****",
"fullname": "For Test Only",
"emails" :[
     { "email": "test1@mail.com", "active": true },
     { "email": "test2@mail.com", "active": true }
]
}
```

And I would like to change to this :

```
{
 "userid": 1234
 "username": "tester",
 "password": "*****",
 "fullname": "For Test Only",
 "emails" :[
     { "email": "test1@mail.com", "active": false},
     { "email": "test2@mail.com", "active": true }
]
}
```

When I tried to change it from my perl script using this :

```
$update_result = $users->update_one(
                                    { 'userid' => $doc->{'userid'}},
                                    { '$set'     => { 'emails.[0].email.active' => false }},
                                    { 'upsert'   => 1}
                                );
```

I got the following result which is NOT expected :

```
{
     "userid": 1234
     "username": "tester",
     "password": "*****",
     "fullname": "For Test Only",
     "emails" :[
         { "active": false},
         { "email": "test2@mail.com", "active": true }
    ]
}
```

The email disappear !! . Any idea why is NOT keeping the email ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `$set` line is wrong -- you have a dangling single quote, and I guess you should have a key to value mapping, whereas you seem to have a value to boolean mapping? Just a guess....it's been a while....

Comment: I don't think so, it's on the right line.

Comment: it does look like a closing single quote is missing here. otherwise it should work like that. `'emails.[0].email.active' => false `

Comment: it was just a mistyping , it's corrected it now. BUT still having the same issue

Comment: I realize you had an extra 'email' in there - the .0 already references the sub-document. I've added an answer, hope it works! (can't test it right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the extra `email.` in there:

```
$update_result = $users->update_one(
                                    { 'userid' => $doc->{'userid'}},
                                    { '$set'     => { 'emails.[0].active' => false }},
                                    { 'upsert'   => 1}
                                );
```